# php list directory 5 files at-a-time

Tags: php, directory, readdir, opendir

I am trying to pull all of the files in a directory, but do it in 5-filename chunks. I can't find an example that doesn't use the `while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)` loop. I thought there used to be a statement similar to this `while(!feof($file))` but for directories, but I can't find it anymore. Any help is appreciated.

This is my best attempt:

```
$dir = "images";
opendir($dir);

while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
{

for ($x=0; $x<=5; $x++)
{
$file = readdir($dh);
echo $file . '<br>';
}

}
closedir($dir);
```

Thanks,

Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
$dir = "images";
opendir($dir);
$continue=true;

while ($continue) {
  for ($x=0; $x<=5; $x++) {
    $file = readdir($dh);
    if ($file===false) {
      $continue=false; //for the while
      break;           //for the for
    }
    echo $file . '<br>';
  }
}

closedir($dir);
```

You could remove the need for the `$continue` flag variable by using `while($file!==false)` but at a cost on readability.

Comment: I sort of used a variation of Eugen's design:

    $dir = "images/weddings";
    $dh = opendir($dir) or exit('oops');
    $loopcount = 0;
    
    while (($filename = readdir($dh)) !== false)
    {
    if(($filename != ".") and ($filename != ".."))
    {
    $loopcount = $loopcount + 1;
    echo '<td style="font-size: 10px;">' . $filename . '</td>';
    
    if ($loopcount == 5)
    {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    $loopcount = 0;
    }
    
    
    }
    }
    closedir($dir);

I wish I could mark both of you as correct answers. Thanks for the great ideas!

doug